# Prove that "equiprobable" is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, uniform-distribution

> Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $n$ and let $R$ be the set of all relations over $X$. Consider the probability space $(R,P)$ with uniform distribution, that is, $P[\{R_1\}]] = P[\{R_2\}]$ for all $ R_1,R_2 \in R$. Define the relation ”equiprobable” on the set of all events of $(R, P)$ as follows: Events $A$ and $B$ are equiprobable iff $P[A] = P[B]$.
>
> a. Prove that ”equiprobable” is an equivalence relation.
>
> b. How many equivalence classes does this relation define?

Here is my attempt at a, can anyone help me check?

- Reflexive: $R_1 ,\in R$, then $P[\{R_1\}] = P[\{R_1\}]$, which is equiprobable $\Rightarrow$ $R_1\,R\, R_1$ $\Rightarrow$ reflexive
- Transitive: $R_1,R_2,R_3 \in R$, suppose $P[\{R_1\}] = P[\{R_2\}\,] \&  \,P[\{R_2\}] = P[\{R_3\}] \,\Rightarrow\, P[\{R_1\}] = P[\{R_3\}] \,\Rightarrow\, R_1 \,R \,R_3 \,\Rightarrow $transitive
- Symmetric: $R_1, R_2 \in R$, $ P[\{R_1\}] = P[\{R_2\}]$ $\Rightarrow$ $P[\{R_2\}] = P[\{R_1\}]$ $\Rightarrow$ $R_2\, R\, R_1$ $\Rightarrow$ symmetric

I don't know how to solve b, and my teacher gave me a hint but I'm still a lot confused about equivalence classes

> If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are equiprobable, is there any relation between $|R_1|$ and $|R_2|$?

This is just my guess: $|R_1| = |R_2|$ because they are equivalence relations, so the size of them are equal?
Please help me understand this

Comment: How many elements does $R$ have?  So how many values can $P$ take?

Comment: @user10354138 erm I'm not sure.. the question doesn't state, does it? Can you give me some more hints?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing math :)

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo I will, thanks

Comment: The equivalence class of an event $A\subseteq R$ is the set of all events $B\subseteq R$ which are equiprobable to $A$. Under the uniform distribution, the only condition to be satisfied is that $A$ and $B$ contain the same number of outcomes. You might as well label each equivalence class by the size of its elements!

Comment: @M.Nestor so you mean there is 1 equivalence class? |R1| = |R2| or in other words [R1] = [R2]?

Comment: The relations $R_1,R_2,R_3,\dots$ are *outcomes* in the probability space, but an *event* is a set containing outcomes. For example $A=\{R_1,R_2,R_3\}$ is an event containing three outcomes, so under the uniform distribution $P$ it is three times more likely than the events $\{R_1\}$ or $\{R_2\}$, since they are events containing just one outcome.

Comment: @drhab so the number of equivalence classes is the number of those values? from 0, 1..., n^2?

Comment: @drhab so by any chance, do you know why my teacher gave me that hint? since if that is the case, I don't really get why |R1| = |R2| is relevant?

Comment: @drhab I see, thank you

Comment: @amV Sorry, I see now that I made an essential mistake, so I have deleted my former comments and also my answer. I hope to come with a better answer during the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $f:A\to B$ is some function then a relation $S$ over $A$ that is prescribed by: $$xSy\iff f(x)=f(y)$$can "immediately" be recognized as an equivalence relation on base of the observations that $f(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in A$, $f(x)=f(y)\implies f(y)=f(x)$ for all $x,y\in A$ and $f(x)=f(y)\wedge f(y)=f(z)\implies f(x)=f(z)$ for all $x,y,z\in A$.

You did that in your attempt with function $P$.

Further the equivalence class represent by $a\in A$ is the set $\{x\in A\mid f(x)=f(a)\}$.

The cardinality of the set of equivalence classes equals the cardinality of the image of the function, i.e. the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}$. This because there is a one-to-one relation between the image and the set of equivalence classes: every element $y$ of this image corresponds with equivalence class $\{x\mid f(x)=y\}$.

---

Application in your situation:

The set of outcomes is $R=\wp\left(X\times X\right)$. From the fact
that $X$ has $n$ elements we conclude that $X\times X$ has $n^{2}$
elements, and secondly that $R=\wp\left(X\times X\right)$ has $2^{n^{2}}$
elements.

Further $P$ is an additive function $\wp\left(R\right)\to\mathbb{R}$
determined by $P\left(\left\{ r\right\} \right)=2^{-n^{2}}$ for every
$r\in R$.

That implies that for event $A\subseteq\wp\left(R\right)$ we have
$P\left(A\right)=\sum_{r\in A}P\left(\left\{ r\right\} \right)=\left|A\right|2^{-n^{2}}$
where $\left|A\right|$ can take the values $\left\{ 0,1,2,\dots,2^{n^{2}}\right\} $.

We conclude that the cardinality of the image of function $P$ is:
$$2^{n^{2}}+1$$ and as shown above this is also the number of equivalence
classes.

Comment: can you explain a little bit about the set of the image of P? why is it {0, 1/n^2, ... (n^2-1)/n^2, 1}? Sorry I'm not quite good at this

Comment: I have repaired my answer.

Comment: Where does the "+ 1" come from for the cardinality of the relation? I'm a little unclear on that part

Comment: @quantumferret Do you agree that set $\{0,1,2,\dots m\}$ has $m+1$ elements? Here $m=2^{n^2}$.

Comment: @drhab would it be incorrect for me to think of it in terms of a probability space (Ω, F, P)? Ω would be _|X x X| = n^2_ and _F = 2^(n^2)_, so _F = m_?

Comment: @quantumferret But we are dealing with probability space $(R,\mathcal P(R),P)$ here, with uniform probability measure $P$. Also our question is not: how many events exist? It is: how many values can be taken by $P$?

Comment: @drhab ohhh ok, and _P_ takes 0 through 2^(n^2), which is 2^(n^2) + 1 possible values.

Comment: @quantumferret Exactly!